# Television app rejected by google play store

Tags: android, television

Reason : APKs and bundles must not require following features: android.software.leanback.

My manifest look like this:

-->

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.television"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="com.oit.wwaystrainingtv.application.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:banner="@drawable/app_banner_logo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute"
    tools:replace="allowBackup,supportsRtl">
```

Comment: why don't you just remove it? the Boolean flag is false unless you aren't explaining the use of it.

Comment: what you mean to remove ? I didn't get your point..

Comment: the leabback 
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />

Comment: if I remove it, would it work on playstore? actually my TV app got refusal from playstore
as msg " APKs and bundles must not require following features: android.software.leanback."

Comment: define work?. As a developer you should have an idea of what services, features, and permission in order for your app to work the way it's intended to. remove it and see if your app works the way it should.